# Remove XML Node based on attribute value with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

My goal is to use this XSLT stylesheet to remove the entire LoanSecondaryStatus node when the StatusDate is 1900-01-01T00:00:00, but otherwise keep the node when it is any other date.

**I have the following XML:**

```
<Loans>
   <Loan>
       <LoanSecondaryStatus>
          <StatusName>Application Started</StatusName>
          <StatusDate>1900-01-01T00:00:00</StatusDate>
      </LoanSecondaryStatus>
      <LoanSecondaryStatus>
          <StatusName>Application Finished</StatusName>
          <StatusDate>2016-03-02T00:00:00</StatusDate>
      </LoanSecondaryStatus>
  </Loan>
</Loans>
```

**And here is the XSLT i'm using to try and remove the LoanSecondaryStatus node:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/LoanSecondaryStatus[not(StatusDate='1900-01-01T00:00:00')]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> remove the entire LoanSecondaryStatus node when the StatusDate is
>   1900-01-01T00:00:00

I believe your 2nd template needs to be:

```
<xsl:template match="LoanSecondaryStatus[StatusDate='1900-01-01T00:00:00']"/>
```

Comment: Yup that worked.  How does that work without the "not"?

Comment: @dc922 Your 1st template is the [identity transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform) template. It copies everything *as is*. The 2nd template provides an exception. It matches the node you want to remove and outputs nothing.